# Angular Routes Are Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, ngroute

I used Angular for a while, but it has changed greatly since I last used it... I'm running into some issues, as I can't get the application to load at all.

When I try to load the individual webpages, I get just the basic HTML, but no error messages... [I'm loading it using the live preview option in Brackets]

The file hierarchy is as follows:

- index.html
- bower_components
- js

-- app.js

-- ctrl

--- about.js

--- home.js

- html

-- home.html

-- about.html

---

The files:

- index.html

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> <html lang="en" np-app="stagerite" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
> <head>
>     <!-- meta tags -->
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
>
>     <!-- title/icon -->
>     <title>StageRite - {{ Page.title() }}</title>
>     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/" />
>
>     <!-- bower imports -->
>     <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
>     <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
>     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
>     <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
>
>     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
>
>     <!-- local css -->
>
>     <!-- local js -->
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ctrl/index.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ctrl/home.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ctrl/about.js"></script>
>
>     <!-- fonts -->
> </head>
>
> <body unresolved fullbleed>
>     <div ng-view></div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

- app.js

> ```
> /*global angular, console, alert*/
>
> (function () {
>     'use strict';
>
>     /* Initialize application. */
>     var stagerite = angular.module('stagerite', [
>         'ngRoute'
>     ]);
>
>     /* Set routes. */
>     stagerite.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
>         $routeProvider.
>             when('/about', {
>                 templateUrl: '../html/about.html',
>                 controller: 'aboutCtrl'
>             }).
>             when('/home', {
>                 templateUrl: '../html/home.html',
>                 controller: 'homeCtrl'
>             }).
>             otherwise({
>                 templateUrl: '../html/home.html',
>                 controller: 'homeCtrl'
>             });
>     }]);
>
>     /* Set page titles. */
>     stagerite.factory('Page', function () {
>         var title = 'Home';
>         return {
>             title: function () {
>                 return title;
>             },
>             setTitle: function (newTitle) {
>                 title = newTitle;
>             }
>         };
>     });
> }());
> ```

- home.html

> ```
> <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
> </div>
> ```

- index.js

> ```
> /*global angular, console, $, alert*/
> /*jslint plusplus: true*/
>
> (function () {
>     'use strict';
>
>     var indexCtrl = angular.module('stagerite', []);
>
>     indexCtrl.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', 'Page', function ($scope, Page) {
>         $scope.Page = Page;
>     }]);
> }());
> ```

- home.js

> ```
> /*global angular, console, $, alert*/
> /*jslint plusplus: true*/
>
> (function () {
>     'use strict';
>
>     var homeCtrl = angular.module('stagerite', []);
>
>     homeCtrl.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Page', function ($scope, Page) {
>         Page.setTitle('Home');
>     }]);
> }());
> ```

Comment: Don't you have a plunker for that?

Comment: So I have to confess I have not really used plunkr with Angular and I'm not positive if I can replicate the file/folder structure (which may actually be the underlying issue?)

Comment: Can't get it with Plunkr either: http://plnkr.co/edit/tVjTovArjjZuYvEXodCT